# Kubuntu not booting after reboot

Tags: linux, kubuntu, home-directory

I am running Kubuntu 14.04, and it was working perfectly fine until the home partition got filled to 100% (my `/` and `/home` are on two different partitions). Many applications began throwing errors about the filled home partition, and it was slow, so I cleaned the partition a bit. But still it wasn't showing the updated free size, so I rebooted. After that, it is not loading.

I can boot into recovery mode, and initially found the home partition, so I cleared it a bit. However, after subsequent reboots the /home directory is empty, leading to my doubt that it is not getting mounted. How can I fix this?

I was able to log in through <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>, and this is the result of `df -h`; part which I consider to be relevant:

```
filesystem    size   used  avail   use%    mounted on
/dev/sda3     24G    9.6G   14G     43%    /
none          4.0K    0     4.0K    0%     /sys/fs/cgroup
udev          1.9G   4.0K   1.9G    1%     /dev
tempfs        390M   1.2M   389M    1%     /run
none          5.0M   0      5.0M    0%     /run/lock
none          2.0G   0      2.0G    0%     /run/shm
none          100M   8.0K   100M    1%     /run/user
/dev/sda5     15G    14G     0     100%    /home
```

So clearly, even when there is 1GB space, it is showing 0% free space. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by deallocating the space for logs. I was under the impression that I had already done that, but I hadn't.